# Matching formal argument does not work if its default is an external variable

Tags: r, arguments, global-variables, parameter-passing, eval

Suppose I'm writing a new `R` package called `myvals`.

I write this in file `zzz.r`:

```
.__COMMONS__. <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
.__COMMONS__.$vals <- c('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
```

Then, if I wrote this function in file `vals.r`:

```
whatvals <- function() {
  return(.__COMMONS__.$vals)
}
```

When I install my package (e.g., through `devtools` package) and load it (i.e., `library(myvals)`), `whatvals()` works:

```
[1] "val1" "val2" "val3"
```

But, if then I write another function:

```
isval <- function(val = .__COMMONS__.$vals) {
  match.arg(val)
}
```

When I call it **it doesn't work** because `R` cannot find `.__COMMONS__.` object.

I think this depends on the lazy evaluation of the formal parameter `val` by `match.arg` function.

Inspecting `match.arg` source code I found that first lines are interesting:

```
if (missing(choices)) {
  formal.args <- formals(sys.function(sys.parent()))
  choices <- eval(formal.args[[deparse(substitute(arg))]])
}
```

So I have two questions for you:

- how to make `.__COMMONS__.` environment correctly evaluated when passed to `val` **formal parameter** of `isval` function?
- there is a more elegant way to create **global variables** for a `R` package?

Thanks in advance.